# Не могу вернуть значение из функции, playground говорит, что значение еще не инициализировано

Tags: функции, swift4

```
var difference : Int {
        var extraPad : Int
        for i in 0 ..< dataSource.numberOfColumns {
        var columnLabelSize = columnLabels[i].count
            for j in 0 ..< dataSource.numberOfRows{
                var itemSize = String(dataSource.itemForRow(row: i, column: j)).count
                if itemSize > columnLabelSize{
                    extraPad = itemSize - columnLabelSize
                }
                else {
                    extraPad = 0
                }
            }
        }
        return extraPad
    }
```